# Connecting to Sql Server with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have just installed Laravel with a fresh install via Composer, and changed Config/database.php to

```
    'default' => 'sqlsrv',
```

And changed the settings for the connection

```
    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'Host IP'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'WebServices'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'User'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'Password'),
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],
```

but i am getting this error when trying to connect.

```
     1/1
PDOException in Connector.php line 47:
SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].

 in Connector.php line 47
at PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=homestead', 'homestead', 'secret', array('0', '2', '0', false)) in Connector.php
line 47 at Connector >createConnection('sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=homestead', array('driver' => 'sqlsrv', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'homestead', 'username' => 'homestead', 'password' => 'secret', 'prefix' => '', 'name' => 'sqlsrv'), array('0', '2', '0', false)) in SqlServerConnector.php
line 29 at SqlServerConnector->connect(array('driver' => 'sqlsrv', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'homestead', 'username' => 'homestead', 'password' => 'secret', 'prefix' => '', 'name' => 'sqlsrv')) in compiled.php 
line 10673 at ConnectionFactory->createSingleConnection(array('driver' => 'sqlsrv', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'homestead', 'username' => 'homestead', 'password' => 'secret', 'prefix' => '', 'name' => 'sqlsrv')) in compiled.php 
line 10669 at ConnectionFactory->make(array('driver' => 'sqlsrv', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'homestead', 'username' => 'homestead', 'password' => 'secret', 'prefix' => ''), 'sqlsrv') in compiled.php line 10587
```

I have no idea why it is doing this Any help would be much appropriated, it's currntly hosted in WAMP   under www/Laravel/

Comment: Is the SQL-Server up and running? Is there a database named `homestead` with the username `homestead` and the password `secret` on `localhost`?

Comment: The .env file did it, i didn't know about that one i just assumed it was the Config/Database.php

Comment: Oh, ok :) In the config-file, with the `env()` function you grab the environment variables which can be defined in the `.env`-file. If there is no variable set, you can pass a default value as the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check app/config/local/database.php file if isset. Probably your configuration infos getting from there.

Answer (score 0):

My environment :

- Windows Server 2008
- SQL Server Express 2014
- Xampp win32 with PHP 5.6.23
- Laravel 5.2

Cause : PDO connection failed because of the TCP/IP Protocols issue.
[SQL Server 2014 Configuration Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q1iY.jpg)

Go to >> Configuration Tools

1. SQL Server 2014 Configuration Manager
2. SQL Server Network Configuration
3. Protocols for "your_sqlserver_service"
4. Right click on TCP/IP, select Properties
5. Choose IP Addresses tab
6. Scroll down to IPALL
7. At TCP Port, key in 1433
8. Ok and restart SQL Server service.

Let's try it. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Also I was caught out with this error when using Xamp with a virtual host. I changed the port from 80 to 8000 but forgot to change the vhosts file to reflect the port change. Just thought I'd add this for any other poor soul.